# Unpacked eigenvectors of complex matrices

Tags: matrix, memory, packed-arrays

**Edit:** This bug is fixed in *Mathematica* 10.0.0

I want to calculate eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix. For example

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
n = 3000;
mat = # + ConjugateTranspose[#] &@RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
evec = Eigenvectors[mat];
```

However, `evec` is unpacked!

```
evec // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> False

System monitor shows

[image]

It seems that the result was unpacked in the end of evaluation. I think the problem is that the last element of each eigenvector is real instead of complex

```
evec[[All, -1]]
```

> ```
> -0.100012, -0.059244, -0.0723702, ...
> ```

```
evec[[All, -2]]
```

> ```
> -0.0994738 - 0.00136552 I, -0.0527357 - 0.0532419 I, 0.158174 + 0.0341157 I, ...
> ```

With real matrices everything is fine

```
n = 5000;
mat = # + Transpose[#] &@RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
evec = Eigenvectors[mat];
evec // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> True

[image]

My current workaround consist in packing the result immediately after `Eigenvectors`

```
evec = Developer`ToPackedArray[0.0 I + Eigenvectors[mat]];
```

Now `evec` is packed but there is a very big peak in the memory usage

[image]

It is not a problem for a small matrices, but if matrix `mat` is ~30GB then I need ~300GB memory. It is quite a lot even for the swap space!

It seems that this is a very simple question, but I could not find anything.

P.S. I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and Linux. *Mathematica* 8 has the same problem.

**Update**

halirutan's answer solves this problem completely! Now memory profile is much better

[image]

Some notes:

You need 11 version of MKL. In Gentoo it is available in science overlay. I compile the library with the command

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o PackedEigenvectors.so -I /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C/ -I /opt/intel/composerxe-2013.0.080/mkl/include/ PackedEigenvectors.c
```

Helpful links: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34033/4678), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23410/4678)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but as a side remark you can see when anything gets unpacked by first switching on the message like so: ``On[Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1]``. Then `evec = Eigenvectors[mat];` gives a warning ``Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {300}. >>``

Comment: @acl Thanks, I know this feature! `On["Packing"]` is more convenient.

Comment: Would it be an option to call the [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) by yourself? The Intel Compiler is free as academic version for Linux. If it is really numerical calculation of EigenVectors only, it could be worth it to call the LAPACK routing by yourself.

Comment: @halirutan Thank you for the idea. Several years ago I used this library. However, it would be great to do whole process (preparation of the matrix, solving the eigensystem, and further analysis) in *Mathematica*. Such very big matrices are rare but even medium-size (~1/10 of RAM) matrices can make a system go into swap and this is annoying. I can't visit this site at this moments :)

Comment: I agree this unpacking is not a nice thing to happen. We'll look into it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me put my comment into an answer, because I think we might have misunderstood each other. You answered in the comment

> However, it would be great to do whole process (preparation of the matrix, solving the eigensystem, and further analysis) in Mathematica.

That exactly was my idea. You only write some lines of C-Code which are compiled into a WolframLibrary function. This can directly be called from within Mathematica. So the only thing you do is, you substitute the call of `Eigenvectors`. For the following, please note that I haven't used the MKL in a while and I basically just copied an example which looked promising.

Here is the [complete Library wrapper code](http://pastebin.com/T2UXEzr0) for the MKL function which calculates the eigensystem of a [complex hermitian matrix](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/zheev.htm#top). The core of the wrapper is the following function

```
DLLEXPORT int zheev(
        WolframLibraryData libData, 
        mint argc, 
        MArgument *args,
        MArgument res) {
    MTensor input = MArgument_getMTensor(args[0]);
    MKL_Complex16 *data = (MKL_Complex16*) libData->MTensor_getComplexData(input);
    const mint *dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(input);

    MKL_INT n = dims[0], info, lda = n;

    double *w = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    info = LAPACKE_zheev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'L', n, data, lda, w);

    if (info > 0) {
        free(w);
        return LIBRARY_NUMERICAL_ERROR;
    }

    MArgument_setMTensor(res, input);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

}
```

This library function expects a complex matrix as input whose numeric values are stored in `data`. Everything depends here on the fact that the WolframLibrary stores its `mcomplex` in the same way as the `MKL_Complex16`. In my case here this means to check whether the memory layout for the following types are identical

```
typedef struct {mreal ri[2];} mcomplex;

typedef struct _MKL_Complex16 {
    double real;
    double imag;
} MKL_Complex16;
```

`mreal` is typedef'd as `double` here. If this is the case then chances are very good that you can

- extract the tensor data from the input matrix (getting a C array of complexes)
- feed this array directly to the MKL routine which stores the eigenvectors by overwriting exactly this array
- return your input tensor back to *Mathematica*

If the C part works, then installing and calling the WolframLibrary is as easy as the next few lines of code

```
AppendTo[$LibraryPath, "/path/where/your/lib/is"];
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["libCallMKL", "zheev", {{_Complex, 2}}, {_Complex, 2}];

On["Packing"]
n = 3000;
mat = # + ConjugateTranspose[#] &@RandomComplex[1, {n, n}];
evec = fun[mat];
```

In my tests, this took fewer memory as the `Eigenvectors` call and it did not unpack the array in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I did not imagine that it is so easy to connect *Mathematica* and MKL. I hope this problem will be solved in the next versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @ybeltukov I think it will be addressed.

Comment: This seems like the best option if one has MKL. If not, perhaps `LinearAlgebra\`LAPACK\`GEEV` could be useful? The problem is that I'm not sure which 9 of the 13 arguments for `*GEEV` are actually required, or in what form and order.

Comment: I just realized that actually you don't use MKL! You use only definitions, but shared library comes from Mathematica itself. You can put [this definitions](http://pastebin.com/YeLF1cmY) instead `#include <mkl_lapacke.h>` and everething will work.