# LibraryUnload fails

Tags: linux, librarylink

I can load my library, but I cannot unload it with `LibraryUnload`. I do have a `void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData)` (which does nothing). I get the following error:

```
LibraryFunction::unloadlib: The library "/my/library.so" cannot be unloaded.
```

I am not loading any function after loading the library. The OS is Linux x86_64.

I don't seem to be able to unload not even the demo library:

```
LibraryLoad@"demo"
LibraryUnload@%
```

This gets me the same error.

EDIT:
As worked out by Szabolcs and halirutan, I need to load one function at least (`LibraryFunctionLoad`) to have the initialization function called, and so being able to call `LibraryUnload` successfully. Yet, my ultimate goal is to be able to reload a new build of the library: this seems impossible because calling `LibraryUnload` doesn't actually close the handle of the library, and further calls to `LibraryFunctionLoad` reuse it. I checked with `lsof`, and if I delete the library and try to reload it I get that the new file is ignored and instead a handle to the old file (tagged correctly as `DEL` in `lsof`) is kept.

Comment: Apparently I cannot unload the demo libraries too. I need this feature because I'm coding this library, and I don't want to restart the kernel each time.

Comment: If you see the issue even with the demo-libraries, can you please make a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) where you exactly show how you load and unload the library-function? I have *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and Ubuntu x86-64 and here, unloading seems to work properly.

Comment: @halirutan done.

Comment: It seems that if I actually load some functions from the library (as [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LibraryUnload.html)) then afterwards I can unload without problems.  But if I don't load any functions (and only use LibraryLoad) then I get the error you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that LibraryLoad won't actually run the library initialization code, it will only load the library.  You can use LibraryLoad to load *any* shared library that your code may need, not only LibraryLink-specific libraries ([see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/how-can-i-use-shared-libraries-in-librarylink-code-and-ensure-mathematica-will-f)).  So it would make sense that it doesn't attempt to run the wolfram library initialization.  Maybe if this is not run then uninitialization fails.  Just guesses.

Comment: I think you're right @Szabolcs . I just tried and loading a function makes the library unloadable... But! This doesn't mean that the library is `dlclose()`'d (I checked with lsof, the handle is still there), which is what I actually want to do, because in the process of developing the library I might want to recompile it, and I don't want to reboot the kernel every time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the intricacies of shared libraries, but when I was writing LibraryLink-based tools, as far as I can remember I didn't have a problem with using LibraryUnload, deleting the library, recompiling, and loading again.  Are you saying this doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, see edit.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone How did you solve the problem in the end? I encountered the same problem. Even I update my library file, Mathematica still uses the old library file until a kernel restart.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I don't think I ever solved the problem in a reliable way, and in general I started avoiding C interoperability with Mathematica, it is in general too clunky. Now I'm using giant dump files between my C code and Mathematica, which is meh but at least I don't get hard crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todd Gayley once mentioned that `LibraryLoad` is for pre-loading depend libraries you need. So for instance, if you write a function which needs some numeric-library, you can load this before calling the functions in your library.

You don't need to pre-load the *WolframLibrary library* you have developed because you implicitly load it by loading the functions in it.

Therefore, I believe the solution to your problem is that you have to call `LibraryFunctionLoad` on one of the functions you are developing and after that `LibraryUnload` should work as expected.

Furthermore, you should unload all functions with `LibraryFunctionUnload` before unloading the library.

Comment: I can confirm that this is how it works. Yet, `LibraryUnload` doesn't close the handle to the library, and if I replace it with a new build, there's no way to unlink the old version from the Kernel.

Comment: Ok, if I `LibraryFunctionLoad` then `LibraryFunctionUnload` a function in my library, the library is correctly unlink from the kernel. If you add this to your answer I'll flag it as accepted

Comment: @LorenzoPistone Sorry for the late reply. I added the information to the answer. You know that you could have done this by yourself. It's one of the basic rules of SE that everyone can edit everything. Don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: haha sorry, I didn't realize after all this time using SO!

Comment: @halirutan: you mention that `LibraryLoad` is needed to pre-load libraries which own libs depend on. This is what I currently need to do, but then I can't unload those libraries (there is no LibraryFunction to load from those). Do you have a solution how I can Unload those dependencies so I can remove them without closing the kernel? I'm afraid that won't work, which I consider an oversight (bug?)...

Comment: @AlbertRetey The [Details section of LibraryUnload](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryUnload.html) says, that you can use it exactly for this: "LibraryUnload will unload a library that does not follow the Wolfram Library specification."

Comment: @halirutan: yes, but that seems to not work, at least not for me on Windows. I'm not sure whether that is a shortcoming of LibraryLink` or of Windows, though. When I try to unload LibraryUnload gives an error message and the kernel still keeps a handle on the corresponding file...

Comment: On OS X, there is more to it: if the library was loaded using `LibraryLoad`, then `LibraryUnload` will simply not work (whether `LibraryFunctionLoad` was used or not).  The only way I found to make `LibraryUnload` work was never to use `LibraryLoad` in the first place.

Comment: Hi @AlbertRetey ! May I ask have you found a solution to your question? I ran into exactly same problem on Windows recently.

Comment: I don't remember really, but I think that I didn't find a solution. For the things I did, I could live with restarting the Kernel, I think...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I just got a solution today from [@ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian): if one appends the path of depended lib to `PATH` environment variable (something like `SetEnvironment["PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <> libpath]`), then one won't need to pre-load the lib with `LibraryLoad` anymore, as Windows will take care of it, as well as ensure it (quote:) "gets unloaded automatically when no longer referenced".

Comment: @Silvia: thanks for mentioning this, will be of great help for me. Would you mind to add this as an answer? I think it would be very valuable to have that as an answer and not only as a hard-to-find and probably non-lasting comment...

Comment: @AlbertRetey You're absolutely right. Done!

Answer (score 3):

(Information worth sharing for Windows users despite the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag in original question.)

As [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38314/libraryunload-fails/38490?noredirect=1#comment279908_38490) mentioned, there is an additional problem on Windows platform, which I will try to describe here, as long as a solution to it.

#### The `LibraryUnload` failure problem on Windows

Suppose one has a "standalone" library ***myLib.dll***, which has nothing to do with Mathematica or LibraryLink. Then one has a ***libLink.dll***, which uses *myLib* and provides functions to Mathematica through LibraryLink.

As *libLink* depends on *myLib*, [one may try to pre-load](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34017/17) *myLib* before loading *libLink*, and it works with no problem:

```
LibraryLoad["myLib.dll"]
myfunc = LibraryFunctionLoad["libLink.dll", ... ]
```

But then, on Windows, if one tries to unload them with

```
LibraryUnload["libLink.dll"]
LibraryUnload["myLib.dll"]
```

The former one will succeed but the latter one will fail with an error message

```
LibraryFunction::unloadlib: The library myLib.dll cannot be unloaded.
```

Using tools such as Process Explorer one can see the file's handle has not been released by the kernel.

#### The solution

The described problem can be frustrating when one is developing *myLib*. One has to kill the kernel each time before re-compiling *myLib*. The solution, which was found and kindly shared to me by [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) (who has very generously reviewed my code and looked into the problem.), is

**NOT to manually pre-load *myLib* with `LibraryLoad` at first place.**

Instead, one may modify the OS environment so Windows can find all the depended libraries and manage them automatically:

```
SetEnvironment["PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <> "path_to_folder_of_myLib.dll"]
myfunc = LibraryFunctionLoad["libLink.dll", ... ]
```

Unloading will now be as simple as:

```
LibraryUnload["libLink.dll"]
```

After that, if there is no other reference to *myLib.dll*, it will be editable.

Comment: Relying on the `PATH` environment variable is not 100% fool proof.  There are ways in which the loader can ignore it.

Comment: @ihojnicki I'm really quit new to C/C++/Windows API/etc. Is there any references on the topic you would recommend to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ihojnicki Ah sorry.. By "the topic" I meant the scenario you mentioned in your comment, that is the case setting `PATH` fails to auto-load/unload dependencies. Could you tell more about that? By no means I was asking for a generic C++/Windows reference.

Comment: The search order reference is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).  It is a bit complicated, but the search order depends on the method the application is distributed and what preferences it sets up beforehand.

Comment: @ihojnicki That is very informative! Thank you!